# iOS 10 navigiation bar tab bar issues

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, swift3

I have the following setup:

UINavigationController > TabBarController -> ViewController

This is using Swift3 and xcode 8.

when I do `self.title` it doesn't work. I'm not able to do it any other way, tried the below:

```
    self.tabBarController!.navigationItem.title = "test"
    self.tabBarController!.navigationController?.title = "test"
    self.tabBarController!.navigationController?.topViewController?.title = "test"
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer was:

```
self.tabBarController!.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Profile"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off if your setup went:

TabBarController -> UINavigationController -> ViewController

and then just coding:

```
self.navigationItem.title = "test"
self.navigationController?.title = "test"
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "test"
self.navigationController?.topViewController?.title = "test"
```

Comment: Problem Is I have several view controllers outside of tab bar controller...cant get rid of that.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your storyboard setup in you question?